# When exact does rspec's before(:all) run?

Tags: ruby, rspec

The question is straight forward, given a pattern that runs multiple `*_spec.rb` files, does `before(:all)` run once before all of the files or before each file? I know `before(:each)` runs before each example but I'm unclear about the other.

If it helps my use case is I want to initialize a selenium instance in `before(:all)` and login to a website. I only want to log in once at the start of the run and destroy the selenium instance at the end of the run rather than initialize/destroy for each `*_spec.rb` file that runs.

I was going to test this by simply putting a `puts` statement in the `before(:all)` block but it doesn't print to screen, just ignores the `puts` call all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `before(:all)` runs once for the example group it is defined in (ie a describe or context block). For clarity it is aliased as `before(:context)` starting with rspec 3.

It sounds like you're after `before(:suite)`

Comment: Yes, I got this working by initializing the selenium instance in the RSpec.configure scope, logging in inside the before(:suite) hook and assigning it as an instance variable inside of before(:all). Actually a pretty clean solution considering. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`before(:all)` will run once before the examples within a given `Describe` block.

This behavior is described in the [RSpec Core 2.0 documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks).  According to the [RSpec Core 3.2 documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks), `before(:context)` provides the same functionality as `before(:all)`.